# Configuring Jmeter Tests in VSTS/TFS (Azure DevOps) through Command Line Task

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, azure-pipelines

I am trying to intergate my Jmeter script in azure devops with the help of below document:
https://medium.com/@ganeshsirsi/configuring-jmeter-tests-in-vsts-tfs-azure-devops-and-publishing-results-dcdd7b451cb9

But I am getting below error when configure the command line task:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YnICD.png)

But when i run the pipeline getting below mentioned error PFA screenshot:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syjJ4.png)

Comment: When you run the pipeline, you can set varibale: `system.debug = true` to get more detailed log. In addition, are you running the pipeline using a private agent?

Comment: @HughLin-MSFT I am using the private agent for running the pipeline. Updated the second image above with the updated debugged log

Comment: Not get your response for several days, would you please share your latest information about this issue? If you have any concern, feel free to share it here.

Answer (score 0):

> Configuring Jmeter Tests in VSTS/TFS (Azure DevOps) through Command
>   Line Task

The reason that **Jmeter Tests** runs with errors is that `ApacheJMeter.jar` file is missing from `C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin` or your `WorkList.jmx` is missing on your root path of the private agent.

**1)** download **Binaries** of [Apache JMeter 5.3](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) which contains `ApacheJMeter.jar`.

[image]

**2)** make sure that `WorkList.jmx` is under your root **Repos** since you use `-n-f-t WorkList.jmx`. So you should check `WorkList.jmx` on your root Repos.

**In a word**, Please keep the relative path of the specified command line under **Run Jmeter Test** consistent with your **Repos**.

[image]